# Problem with TK Dodge and Character Behaviors Enhanced

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I want to have both [TK Dodge](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/20923?tab=files) and [Character Behaviors Enhanced](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/90552/?tab=files)  but both of these mods have one same file (**1hm_behavior.hkx**). But I can't have both of them at the same time. Can someone give me a solution how to have these 2 thing at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

*1hm_behavior.hkx* is a shared file used by many mods like Ultimate Combat, TK Combat, PCEA, Character Behaviors Enhanced etc.

[Character Behaviors Enhanced](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/90552/?tab=files) comes with a No Dodging version. If you use TK Dodge, then go for this version.

Alternatively, you can try and see if a patch is available.